# Ionic side menu items back navigation

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I am trying to accomplish both tabs and sliding side menu, but can't get back button appear after entering side menu item. I am new to Ionic/Angular Routing,but I am supposing that to make it work I need to manipulate with app.js and states.

```
<ion-side-menus>
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable bar-positive">
      <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon" ng-click="toggleRight()"></button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <header class="bar bar-header bar-balanced">
      <h1 class="title">MyApp</h1>
    </header>
    <ion-content class="has-header">
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item menu-close ui-sref="about">
          About
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

And my apps.js looks like this:

```
.state('tab', {
        url: '/tab',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
      })

 (...tab states...)

 .state('about', {
    url: '/about',
    templateUrl: 'templates/side/about.html',
    controller: 'AboutController',
  })
```

What should I do make back nav-button(or at least make some custom button on navigation bar to redirect home) appear when I am entering one of the side menu items and then template?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

$ionicNavBarDelegate.showBackButton(true);

[$ionicNavBarDelegate api guide](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicNavBarDelegate/)

Answer (score 0):

You can include below code to enable back button.

> < ion-side-menus  enable-menu-with-back-views="true">
>   ....
>   < /ion-side-menus>

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSideMenus/

Comment: This is not my case, it defines whether to hide side menu icon or not when back button appears. In my case, back button doesnt appear.

Comment: In your html, <ion-nav-back-button> is empty. Have you tried including icon  in it. <ion-nav-back-button class="button"><i class="icon icon-left ion-ios-arrow-back"></i></ion-nav-back-button>

Comment: Back button works, I have a view with child views where arrows appear correctly. So i'm sure its not the problem.